# React Native : How to open the menu of the selected flatlist item only

Tags: react-native, mobile

hey i have a flatlist and a menu for each item but the menus are getting stacked on top of eachother and are being opened together. so when i press on the icon on the side of a flatlist item five menus are opened at once (which is the same number of items i have), to fix this i need to setVisibile = true to only the selected item but i m failing to do so.

```js
  <FlatList style={DocumentStyle.flatstyle}
              keyExtractor={(item)=>item['id']}
              data={filteredfile}
              renderItem={({item})=>( 
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate('Document',{url:{uri: `${item.file}`}})}>
                  <View  style={DocumentStyle.flatitem}>
                      <Icon style={DocumentStyle.pdf} name="file-pdf-o" color="#666"/>
                      <Text style={DocumentStyle.itemtext}> {item.title}</Text>
                        <Menu
                              visible={visible}
                              onDismiss={closeMenu}
                              anchor={ <TouchableOpacity onPress={openMenu}>
                                          <Icon style={DocumentStyle.ellipsis}  name="ellipsis-v" />
                                        </TouchableOpacity>}>
                              <Menu.Item onPress={() => {console.log('ok')}} title="Rename"/>
                              <Divider />
                              <Menu.Item onPress={() => {console.log('ok')}} title="Label"/>
                              <Divider />
                              <Menu.Item onPress={() => {console.log('ok')}} title="Delete" />
                        </Menu>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity> )}
              />
```

this is openMenu function:

```js
const openMenu=()=>{
 setVisible(true)}
```

i know the work should be on this function but all i tried was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a menu for each item, just create one menu and pass its content as props from the flatlistItem

```
const openMenu=()=>{setMenuContent("your content here") setVisible(true)}
```